# Output not printing after switch case utilized Java

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I'm working on using enum / switch case along with Zeller's formula for saying what day of the year a specific date will be. My code was printing the right days before I implemented the enum / switch portion of my code (below). After I put in the enum/ switch case, when I run it in DrJava it does prompt for the day, the month and the year, but nothing prints once it goes through the switch case

```
 import java.util.*;

public class Zeller {

  public enum DaysOftheWeek {

    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY;
  }

  private static int value;



  public Zeller (int value){
    this.value = value;
  }
  public int getValue(){
    return this.value;
  }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      DetermineDay(value);        // Create a Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompt the user to enter a year, month and a day


        System.out.print("Enter month: 1-12: ");
        int month = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the day of the month: 1-31: ");
        int day = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter year (e.g., 2008): ");
        int year = input.nextInt();

        // Check if the month is January or February
        // If the month is January and February, convert to 13, and 14,
        // and year has to -1. (Go to previous year).
        if (month == 1 || month == 2) {
            month += 12;
            year--;
        }

        // Compute the answer
        int k = year % 100; // The year of the century
        int j = (int)(year / 100.0); // the century
        int q = day;
        int m = month;
      int h = (q + (int)((13 * (m + 1)) / 5.0) + k + (int)(k / 4.0)

           + (int)(j / 4.0) + (5 * j)) % 7;
      value = h;

      System.out.println(value);

    }

    public static String DetermineDay(int value){

        String result = "Day of the week is "; 

    switch (value){

      case 1 :
        System.out.println(result + "Sunday");
        break;
      case 2 :
        System.out.println(result + "Monday"); 
        break;
      case 3:
      System.out.println(result + "Tuesday");
      break;
      case 4:
        System.out.println(result + "Wednesday");

        break;
      case 5:
        System.out.println(result + "Thursday"); 
        break;

      case 6:
        System.out.println(result + "Friday"); 
        break;
      case 7 :
        System.out.println( result + "Saturday");
        break;
      default : 
        System.out.println ("Looks like that day doesn't exist");
        break;
    }


   return result;     
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `DetermineDay`?

Comment: Since you haven't shared how you call `DetermineDay`, we cannot tell what happens after that call.

Comment: Pretty sure you've forgotten to call your method. You also probably want to give your method a parameter for `value`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize I had to call it. I just updated that in my code to call it in the main method, I reran it and I'm still not getting a printed output for the day

Comment: @JohnG I just tested to see what the value is after making it equal h, and it is the correct value. I also inserted break statements after each switch case and I'm still not getting a printed out String of the corresponding day to the value

Comment: Can you update the code in your question to reflect your changes?

Comment: @DrewKennedy Just did

Comment: Call `DetermineDay()` at the *end* of your `main()` method.

Comment: @DrewKennedy That did it! It is printing the output correctly now. I've been coding in java for a little over 2 months, so thanks for the help

Comment: No worries. This is just proof that a few little bugs can completely cripple a program. Just remember the order of execution for a program in the future. Calling your function at the top of the main method resulted in `value` being 0 because it hadn't been initialized yet. At the bottom you set `value` to be `h`, so calling it under there is what makes sense. Good luck with your programming endeavors!

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to output the day using DetermineDay you need to call that method at the end after you did the calculation and assigned the result to value.
- This seems to work but there is a problem in your algorithm when trying this program with the date 4/11/2016 it does find that it is a Friday, but when using the date 5/5/2016 which is today the output is *¨Looks like that day doesn't exist¨*, so yeah there is that.
- At the end of DetermineDay you dont need to return a result since you already sop the result inside the switch.

  ```
  import java.util.*;

  public class Zeller {
   public enum DaysOftheWeek {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY;
   }

   private static int value;

   public Zeller (int value){
    this.value = value;
   }

   public int getValue(){
    return this.value;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Prompt the user to enter a year, month and a day
    System.out.print("Enter month: 1-12: ");
    int month = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the day of the month: 1-31: ");
    int day = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter year (e.g., 2008): ");
    int year = input.nextInt();

    // Check if the month is January or February
    // If the month is January and February, convert to 13, and 14,
    // and year has to -1. (Go to previous year).
    if (month == 1 || month == 2) {
      month += 12;
      year--;
    }

    // Compute the answer
    int k = year % 100; // The year of the century
    int j = (int)(year / 100.0); // the century
    int q = day;
    int m = month;
    int h = (q + (int)((13 * (m + 1)) / 5.0) + k + (int)(k / 4.0) + (int)(j / 4.0) + (5 * j)) % 7;
    value = h;

    System.out.println(value);
    DetermineDay(value);
   }

   public static void DetermineDay(int value){
    String result = "Day of the week is "; 

    switch (value){
     case 1 :
      System.out.println(result + "Sunday");
      break;

      case 2 :
       System.out.println(result + "Monday"); 
       break;

      case 3:
       System.out.println(result + "Tuesday");
       break;

      case 4:
       System.out.println(result + "Wednesday");
       break;

      case 5:
       System.out.println(result + "Thursday"); 
       break;

      case 6:
       System.out.println(result + "Friday"); 
       break;

      case 7 :
       System.out.println( result + "Saturday");
       break;

      default : 
       System.out.println ("Looks like that day doesn't exist");
       break;
    }
   }
  }
  ```